# No overload for Method takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, xna

I'm currently working on a game in XNA for my school project.
Its including paddle and a ball and the idea is to force the ball to leave top border and then you proceed to next harder level and you go until you die.
So this is how my victory-detecting piece of code looks like:

```
if (position.Y < 0 && pbcollide == true)
{
     MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Level cleared!", "Nice job", 0);
     paddle.SetInStartPosition();
     paddle.lvcounter++;
}
```

That piece of code is in my `CheckCollisionWall` method in my `Ball` class and `pbcollide` is `bool` var I get from Method `CheckCollisionPaddle`. I have divided classes for `Ball` and `Paddle`, and `SetInStartPosition` is `Paddle` class method and `lvcounter` is `Paddle` class variable that I use to count levels and increase ball and decrease paddle speed, spawn more powerups etc.

The problem occours in my `BallUpdate` method where I call for `CheckCollisionWall` Method

```
public void Update()
{
     position += motion * ballSpeed;
     CheckCollisionWall();
     OffBottom();
}
```

It says no Overload for that method takes 0 arguments. Which arguments should I put there? I really don't know what to do. 
I also tried to put my win condition in totaly new method to avoid this but when I do that game starts without errors but absolutely nothing happens when conditions are fulfilled. So I'm totally confused.

Comment: put your cursor inside parantheses and press Ctrl + P. it shows you the parameters list.

Comment: You need to pass position  to CheckCollisionWall();

Comment: when i press Ctrl P my printing dialog opens
and when i pass position error still there :/

Comment: where is CheckCollisionWall() method is defined ??

Comment: just below the method im calling it in, same class.
Vectors2 position and motion are defined in that same class

Comment: You provided a lot of detail which irrelevant for the problem you are facing. And you did not provide enough relevant Detail: We see the error comes form the call to `CheckCollisionWall()` but we do not see the definition of this method. With these two lines alone, the answer will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

How to solve

> No overload for Method takes X arguments

1. Find out which call causes this compiler error. (In your case it is the call `CheckCollisionWall();`
2. Have a close look at the number and types of arguments in this call. (In your case it is zero arguments)
3. Find *all* definitions of this method. (You may use `Find` or `Find Usages` or intellisense in Visual studio)
4. Compare all definitions/overloads with your call.

The error is caused, when you *use* a call with a different number of arguments or when at least one argument has a different type when compared to the available definitions/overloads.